# How I duplicate the following condition in Python?

Tags: python, ruby, exploit

The following if condition is in Ruby code and I need to duplicated it in Python:

```
# CpqElm-Login: success
if res.headers['CpqElm-Login'].to_s =~ /success/
  cookie = res.get_cookies.scan(/(Compaq\-HMMD=[\w\-]+)/).flatten[0] || ''
end
```

In case you need all the Ruby original code, you can check this link: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/exploits/multi/http/hp_sys_mgmt_exec.rb

Currently I have this:

```
cookie = ''
response_headers = resp.headers.get('CpqElm-Login')
response_cookie = resp.cookies.get('').value  #here is were I need this part " (/(Compaq\-HMMD=[\w\-]+)/).flatten[0]" in Python    

        if 'success' in response_headers:
            cookie = response_cookie
```

Comment: Whats the exact purpose of this condition ? I don't know Ruby, but it's just a matter of checking for the Compaq-HMMD cookie and retrieving its value, right?

Comment: @baptiste0928 this condition means that the "CpqElm-Login" header matches the regular expression `/success/`. Then `res.get_cookies.scan(/(Compaq\-HMMD=[\w\-]+)/).flatten[0]` means scan the the string of cookies and pull the first match of "Compaq-HMMD= some set of numbers and hyphens", if this does not exist then `cookie = ''` (empty string)

Comment: You need to do some regex in python. Start here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html